# accessing DB2 database connection by squirrel sql client

Tags: db2

I am Ramashankar actually I am using Ubuntu OS . When I try to connect with DB2 database through Squirrel sql client it shows the connection is successful but no database table shows after connecting and in logs the error which is coming

> Error: [jcc][t4][10335][10366][3.67.26] Invalid operation: Connection
>   is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=08003 SQLState:  08003 ErrorCode:
>   -4470

I don't know what it is, can someone help me on this

Comment: Is DB2 also on Ubuntu?